# Calculate "age at first record" for each ID

Tags: r, datetime, dplyr

**Background**

I've got a dataset `d` on use of services for members (shown as `ID`) of an organization. Here's a toy example:

```
d <- data.frame(ID = c("a","a","b","b"),                  
                dob = as.Date(c("2004-04-17","2004-04-17","2009-04-24","2009-04-24")),                  
                service_date = as.Date(c("2018-01-01","2019-07-12","2014-12-23","2016-04-27")),stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

It looks like this:

[image: what d looks like]

Besides `ID`, it's got a date of birth `dob` and dates of service `service_date` for each time the member has used the organization's service.

**Problem**

I'd like to add a new column `age_first_record` that represents -- you guessed it -- a member's age at their first `service_date`. Ideally, this figure should be in years, not days. So if you're 13 years and one month old, the figure would be 13.08. The number should repeat within `ID`, too, so whatever that `ID`'s age at their first `service_date` was, that's the number that goes in every row for that `ID`.

What I'm looking for is something that looks like this:

[image: desired_result]

**What I've Tried**

So far, I'm messing with the `MIN` function a bit, like so:

```
d <- d %>% 
  mutate(age_first_rec = min(d$service_date-d$dob))
```

But I can't seem to (a) get it work "within" each `ID` and (b) express it in years, not days. I'm not too familiar with working with datetime objects, so forgive the clumsiness here.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `difftime` to get the difference in `day`s and divide by 365

```
library(dplyr)
d %>% 
   group_by(ID) %>%
   mutate(age_first_record =  as.numeric(difftime(min(service_date), 
       dob, unit = 'day')/365)) %>%
   ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 x 4
  ID    dob        service_date age_first_record
  <chr> <date>     <date>                  <dbl>
1 a     2004-04-17 2018-01-01              13.7 
2 a     2004-04-17 2019-07-12              13.7 
3 b     2009-04-24 2014-12-23               5.67
4 b     2009-04-24 2016-04-27               5.67
```

Comment: I'm getting several decimals here -- any way to keep it at 2 decimal places?

Comment: @logjammin you can just round i.t. `round(as.numeric(...), 2)`  Regarding the `tibble` format, it is print format in tibble, which you may need to change with `options(pillar.sigfig = 2)`